# How can I make a draggable split panel with Elm (preferably Elm-UI)?

Tags: elm

I looked for a split-pane for Elm and found things that don't seem straightforward to use.

doodledood/elm-split-pane is not compatible with Elm 0.19.1, so I guess I would either have to switch to Elm 0.18, or convert this to Elm 0.19.1 to use it. Also it is defined in terms of Elm HTML, not Elm UI.

I also found https://github.com/ellie-app/ellie/blob/master/assets/src/Ellie/Ui/SplitPane.elm. That involves a bunch of custom JavaScript, and it's not obvious to me how tightly coupled it is with the rest of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a split pane in my elm project with elm-ui. I took this SplitPane elm-html-based package https://github.com/doodledood/elm-split-pane, copied it's source into my project and converted its internals to return Element msg from its view function by wrapping the content and the attributes.

Here is the source code of the converted functions:

```
view : ViewConfig msg -> Element msg -> Element msg -> State -> Element msg
view (ViewConfig viewConfig) firstView secondView (State state) =
    let
        splitter =
            getConcreteSplitter viewConfig state.orientation state.dragState
    in
    case state.orientation of
        Horizontal ->
            row
                (paneContainerStyle state.orientation
                    ++ [ width fill ]
                )
                [ el (firstChildViewStyle (State state)) firstView
                , splitter
                , el (secondChildViewStyle (State state)) secondView
                ]

        Vertical ->
            column (paneContainerStyle state.orientation)
                [ el (firstChildViewStyle (State state)) firstView
                , splitter
                , el (secondChildViewStyle (State state)) secondView
                ]


viewReversed : ViewConfig msg -> Element msg -> Element msg -> State -> Element msg
viewReversed (ViewConfig viewConfig) firstView secondView (State state) =
    let
        splitter =
            getConcreteSplitter viewConfig state.orientation state.dragState
    in
    case state.orientation of
        Horizontal ->
            row
                (paneContainerStyle state.orientation
                    ++ [ width fill ]
                )
                [ el (secondChildViewStyle (State state)) secondView
                , splitter
                , el (firstChildViewStyle (State state)) firstView
                ]

        Vertical ->
            column (paneContainerStyle state.orientation)
                [ el (secondChildViewStyle (State state)) firstView
                , splitter
                , el (firstChildViewStyle (State state)) firstView
                ]


getConcreteSplitter :
    { toMsg : Msg -> msg
    , splitter : Maybe (CustomSplitter msg)
    }
    -> Orientation
    -> DragState
    -> Element msg
getConcreteSplitter viewConfig orientation4 dragState =
    case viewConfig.splitter of
        Just (CustomSplitter splitter) ->
            splitter

        Nothing ->
            case createCustomSplitter viewConfig.toMsg <| createDefaultSplitterDetails orientation4 dragState of
                CustomSplitter defaultSplitter ->
                    defaultSplitter
```

Here are the styles functions:

```
paneContainerStyle : Orientation -> List (Attribute msg)
paneContainerStyle orientation5 =
    [ style "overflow" "hidden"
    , style "display" "flex"
    , style "flexDirection"
        (case orientation5 of
            Horizontal ->
                "row"

            Vertical ->
                "column"
        )
    , style "justifyContent" "center"
    , style "alignItems" "center"
    , style "width" "100%"
    , style "height" "100%"
    , style "boxSizing" "border-box"
    ]
        |> List.map Element.htmlAttribute


firstChildViewStyle : State -> List (Attribute msg)
firstChildViewStyle (State state) =
    case state.splitterPosition of
        Px px2 ->
            let
                v =
                    (String.fromFloat <| toFloat (getValue px2)) ++ "px"
            in
            case state.orientation of
                Horizontal ->
                    [ style "display" "flex"
                    , style "width" v
                    , style "height" "100%"
                    , style "overflow" "hidden"
                    , style "boxSizing" "border-box"
                    , style "position" "relative"
                    ]
                        |> List.map Element.htmlAttribute

                Vertical ->
                    [ style "display" "flex"
                    , style "width" "100%"
                    , style "height" v
                    , style "overflow" "hidden"
                    , style "boxSizing" "border-box"
                    , style "position" "relative"
                    ]
                        |> List.map Element.htmlAttribute

        Percentage p ->
            let
                v =
                    String.fromFloat <| getValue p
            in
            [ style "display" "flex"
            , style "flex" v
            , style "width" "100%"
            , style "height" "100%" -- pz edit
            , style "overflow" "hidden"
            , style "boxSizing" "border-box"
            , style "position" "relative"
            ]
                |> List.map Element.htmlAttribute


secondChildViewStyle : State -> List (Attribute msg)
secondChildViewStyle (State state) =
    case state.splitterPosition of
        Px _ ->
            [ style "display" "flex"
            , style "flex" "1"
            , style "width" "100%"
            , style "height" "100%"
            , style "overflow" "hidden"
            , style "boxSizing" "border-box"
            , style "position" "relative"
            ]
                |> List.map Element.htmlAttribute

        Percentage p ->
            let
                v =
                    String.fromFloat <| 1 - getValue p
            in
            [ style "display" "flex"
            , style "flex" v
            , style "width" "100%"
            , style "height" "100%"
            , style "overflow" "hidden"
            , style "boxSizing" "border-box"
            , style "position" "relative"
            ]
                |> List.map Element.htmlAttribute
```

Uri

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach but personally found the combination of html and elm-ui very confusing. (This is me, YMMV.) My simpler approach is just to use an elm-ui scrollbar with a custom thumb.

```
contentArea : Model -> Element Msg
contentArea model =
    let
        leftPane =
            column
                [ width fill, alignTop ]
                [ ... ]

        rightPane =
                column [ spacing 5, padding 5, alignTop, centerX ]
                    [ ... ]

        splitter =
            Input.slider
                [ height <| px 2
                , width <| px 1000
                , centerY
                , behindContent <|
                    -- Slider track
                    el
                        [ width fill
                        , height <| px 1
                        , centerY
                        , centerX
                        ]
                        none
                ]
                { onChange = ResizeViews << round
                , label =
                    Input.labelHidden "Splitter"
                , min = 0.0
                , max = toFloat 1000
                , step = Just 1
                , value = toFloat model.splitInPixels
                , thumb = customThumb
                }

        customThumb =
            Input.thumb
                [ width (px 3)
                , height (px 600)
                , moveDown 300
                , Border.rounded 1
                , Border.width 1
                , Border.color (rgb 0.5 0.5 0.5)
                , Background.color FlatColors.BritishPalette.seabrook
                ]
    in
    column [ width fill, spacing 5, padding 5 ]
        [ splitter
        , row [ width fill, spacing 5, padding 5 ]
            [ el [ width <| fillPortion model.splitInPixels, alignTop ] leftPane
            , el [ width <| fillPortion (1000 - model.splitInPixels), alignTop ] rightPane
            ]
        ]
```